# I can't insert NULL values into datetime2 fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cakephp, null

I'm using CakePHP. When trying to insert a null value into a field it turns into 1900-01-01 00:00:00.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
$this->save(array(
        'date_signed' => null
    ));
```

What seems to be the error and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does DB column have a default constraint?

Comment: Does your date_signed column allow nulls?

Comment: yes, default is set to null and it does allow nulls

Comment: I know nothing about CakePHP but would assume that the conversion to `1900-01-01 00:00:00` must be happening at that end. Perhaps run SQL Profiler just to verify whether it is sending `NULL` or `1900-01-01 00:00:00` and update your question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server does not appear to have a NULL date value, instead it uses a minimum value which is what you are seeing here. For standard SQL DateTime2 the minimum value is `0001-01-01 00:00:00`